# Find all hard links of a certain file

Tags: c, linux, hardlink

I have a filename for which I have to get all `hard links`(that are in the same dir).

I thought about using `readlink` in combination with `dir->d_name` maneuver, but that only applys to softlinks.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will have to compare the inode numbers (`d_ino`) of all of the files in the dir to the given file at hand.

Comment: @DavidRTribble That sounds perfect, could you write up the answer please :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go through each file in the directory and `lstat()` it. If its inode number (`st_ino`) is the same as the one of the file you're interested in, and they both have the same link count (`st_nlink`) which is greater than 1, then they're hard-linked together.

(The link count check isn't *strictly* necessary, but it's a good sanity check.)

Comment: It's a good idea to also compare the `st_devno` device number of each file, to ensure that the files/inodes are located on the same device.